# Image keeps flickering when updating

Tags: php, javascript, image, gd, imagettftext

Try to resize the image, or change the color. the image flickers:

[Click here to see a live example](http://buildworx-mc.com/k/font/fonts/) (Choose a font then click update)

**PHP:**

```
    <?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 64);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 64, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = $_GET['t']; // text
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'fonts/' . $_GET['f'] . '.ttf'; // font

$color = $_GET['c'];
$red = hexdec(substr($color, 0, 2));
$green = hexdec(substr($color, 2, 2));
$blue = hexdec(substr($color, 4, 2));

$font_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $red, $green, $blue);

$size = $_GET['s'];

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 5, 30, $font_color, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function()
        {
            $.farbtastic('#colorpicker', function(color)
            {
                $('#color').val(color);
                updateImage();
            });

            $('#color').blur(function()
            {
                $.farbtastic('#colorpicker').setColor($(this).val());
                updateImage();
            });

            $('#update-btn').click(function()
            {
                updateImage();
            });

        });

        function updateImage()
        {
            $('.sample-text').attr('style', 'background:url(preview.php?s='+$('#font-size').val()+'&c='+$('#color').val().substr(1)+'&f='+$('#font').val()+'&t=' + $('#sample-text').val().replace(' ', '+') + ')');
        }

        function update(value)
        {
            $('#range-display').text(value);
            updateImage();
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
            <select id="font">
                <option>Choose a Font</option>
                <option value="dandy">Dandy</option>
                <option value="wtf">Pixel Font</option>
            </select>
            <input id="font-size" type="range" min="14" max="70" value="25" onchange="update(this.value)" /><span id="range-display">25</span>
            <input type="text" id="sample-text" placeholder="Sample text" />
            <input type="button" value="Update" id="update-btn" />
            <div id="colorpicker"></div>
            <input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" />
            <div class="sample-text"></div>
        </div>
```

As you can see, once updating the size and color, it'll flicker. How can I stop that?

Comment: i get no flicker on FF\chrome\IE

Comment: hm, try to change the size after updating, or change the color after updating.

Comment: its because its not drawn on the client - it has to make a request, process the image then send it back.

Answer (score 2):

You are constantly updating the `background` property, so it has to fetch the image again for every single pixel of resizing. Obviously, it can't do that instantly, so you get flicker.

Instead, try changing the `background-size`, and set a `setTimeout` to update the background image with a different size. You might still get a brief flicker, but nothing near as bad as what you have now. You will also save immense amounts of bandwidth.

Comment: The only other method I could think to add would be to create the image via javascript (loading it in to cache) and then swapping it out. Might eliminate the flash as well.
Some details about detecting image load are on the jQuery forum:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/simple-image-load-detection-with-load